# QueryPerformanceFrequency wrong output when called very fast

Tags: c++, c, timer

When I call `QueryPerformanceCounter` many times in a shot time, it gives me a wrong output. The code is working an amount of loop iteration, and at a point the `QueryPerformanceCounter` returns 2 consecutive different values.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//timer (us)
double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

//prototypage
double micros(void);
void StartCounter(void);

int main()
{
    StartCounter();

    //initialisation time
    printf("go\n");

    for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i += 1) { 
        double time_stamp1 = micros();
        double time_stamp2 = micros();

        if (fabs(time_stamp1 - time_stamp2) > 1000) {
            printf("time_stamp1 : %lf\n", time_stamp1);
            printf("time_stamp2 : %lf\n", time_stamp2);
            printf("i : %ld\n", i);
            break;
        }     
    }   
    printf("finish\n");
 }

void StartCounter() {
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li)) {
        printf("not initialized");
    }
    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart) / 1000000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}

double micros() {
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart - CounterStart) / PCFreq;
}
```

**Unexpected output:**

```
go
time_stamp1 : 709840.300000
time_stamp2 : 712229.000000
i : 5524494
finish
```

Comment: You can't expect every instruction is executed at the same time. Output is expected, because two timestamps are not retrieved at the same time.

Comment: WIndows is not a real-time O/S - anything could have happened between those two time stamps taken.

Comment: I know but the execution time beetwen the 2 time_stamps is about a microsecond. And at given point the execution time is more than 1000 microseconds, this is what I underline with thise piece of code

Comment: your process probably got interrupted so that windows could do something else, there is nothing unexpected about that

Comment: `QueryPerformanceCounter` is also slow by itself